# In pandas getting error 'int' object has no attribute 'index' when try to color few value of a column of a dataframe using style.applymap()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, apply

When trying to color few cell values of a particular Column from a list of rows index, using style.applymap() in pandas, I'm getting error 'int' object has no attribute 'index'. I have no idea why dataframe is behaving like this?

```
def highlight_col(x, lst):
    r = 'color: red'
    df = pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
    for i in lst:
        df.iloc[i:1, 0] = r
    return df

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[10,11,12,13,14], 'name':['Rahul', 'Ravi', 'Mike', 'Nair', 'Mona'], 'age':[30,40,23,45,12], 'street_no':['E112', 'B115', 'C119', 'H112', 'J091']})

lst = (1, 3, 5) # list of row numbers

style1 = df1.style.applymap(lambda x: highlight_col(x, lst))

style1

Error: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'index'
```

Comment: Not sure why no one answers your problem nearly 5 hours. But I strongly recommend you read some example to understand how `.style.applymap` works.

Comment: I searched alot but still not able to figure out hence looking for help. I have the idea to set the color when we have a particular matching condition in apply() function but not have idea how to pass a list of values to color only of dataframe?

Comment: You can have a look at https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/style.html#Finer-Control-with-Slicing.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, to conditionally red-color the column `id`, you can try this *basic approach* with [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html) :

```
def highlight_col(ser, col, lst):
    return ["color: red"
            if i == df1.columns.get_loc(col) and ser.name+1 in lst
            else "" for i in range(len(df1)-1)]

style1 = df1.style.apply(highlight_col, col="id", lst=[1, 3, 5], axis=1)
```

Or in a pandorable way, use slicing with [`IndexSlice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.IndexSlice.html) :

```
lst = [1, 3, 5]

df1.style.applymap(lambda x: "color: red", subset=pd.IndexSlice[[i-1 for i in lst], "id"])
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: Thanaks Timeless, superb approach, could you let me know what "ser" is reference to here?  Is it reference to df1 then what ser.name+1 is doing? Could you elaborate bit more?

Comment: 1) In each iteration, `ser` is a [`Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) that hold the values of each *single row* and hence the Series name is the row index (*by default*). So, when we call `ser.name` we actually ask for the Series name (*aka* the row number). 2) And why the `+1`, because the indexing of your list `[1, 3, 5]` starts at 1 while the indexing of the rows in a *DataFrame* starts at 0.

Comment: Most easy and faster solution which I created is to take all the ids as list then use style.apply(), see the solution. df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[10,11,12,13,14], 'name':['Rahul', 'Ravi', 'Mike', 'Nair', 'Mona'], 'age':[30,40,23,45,12], 'street_no':['E112', 'B115', 'C119', 'H112', 'J091']})
# style1 = df1.style.applymap(lambda value:'color: red' if value in [11, 13, 14] else None,) # slower
style1 = df1.style.applymap(lambda v:'color: red' if v in [11, 13, 14] else None, subset=df.columns[0]) #faster
style1

Comment: That makes no sense because in your question you have a list of row numbers and not a list of some values of the column id. Anyways, I wish you good luck with your work ;)

Comment: Thats true but objective was to color the values so just did it with some tweak.